# How to understand the four tables join query

Tags: sql, join

My question is based on the answer from asemprini87 from this link:[How to Join 4 tables in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42630204/how-to-join-4-tables-in-sql).  (please check the original tables through this link, if you are interested).

My question focuses on: how to understand the last join, and why the syntax is right: the two tables(p, pe) at the last join on condition, not related to based table (f)?

Because I also face the same problem: there are 4 tables, but no one table related to the other three, I found the answer from that link, the answer is correct, but I don't understand why it can link like that.

```
SELECT 
    f.nomeFornecedor, 
    e.idEncomenda, 
    p.nomeProduto,
    pe.quantidade
FROM 
    Fornecedor as f
INNER JOIN 
    Encomenda AS e ON f.idFornecedor = e.idFornededor 
INNER JOIN 
    Produto_Encomenda as pe ON e.idEncomenda = pe.idEncomenda
INNER JOIN 
    Produto as p ON p.idProduto = pe.idProduto
```

Thank you.

Comment: perhaps: idProduto and idEncomenda both have same value.. it looks like a bad table design but doesn't mean there isn't an intention for these relationships.

Comment: Thanks. I might not explain my question very clearly before, and edited again.

Comment: Please put what is needed to ask your question in your post, not just at a link.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making multiple joins, not all of the tables need to relate to a single table, there just needs to be a chain of relationships that link each additional table to one of the previous tables.

Let's look at a simpler example where we have 4 tables: A, B, C, and D.

- A is related to B
- B is related to C
- C is related to D

So, tables C and D aren't directly related to A, but through the chain of relationships we can find the correct rows across all the tables with a process something like this:

1. Take a set of rows from table A
2. Use the relationship between A and B to the related rows from table B
3. Use the relationship between B and C to find the related rows in table C
4. Use the relationship between C and D to find the related rows in table D

Comment: Yes, the relationship is exactly as what you described. Your first sentence points out the key confused part of my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

**My question focuses on: How to understand the last join, and why the syntax is right: the two tables(p, pe) at the last join on condition, not related to based table (f)?**

Its related to (f) only through the other tables...not directly.

The last JOIN connnects Producto(p) and Produto_Encomenda(pe) on idProducto

Encomenda(e) is joined to Produto_Encomenda (pe) on idEncomenda

finally Fornecedor(f) is joined to Encomenda(e) ON idFornededor

Comment: @Annie Your welcome...any amount of time learning TSQL is well spent...https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp
Good luck and welcome to SO